# Windows server closes TCP connection immediately after sending SYN+ACK

Tags: tcp, connection

After a proper SYN, SYN+ACK and ACK TCP-Handshake, the server immediately sends a FIN+ACK indicating a graceful connection closure. The client's HTTP requests results in RST packets from server. This happens once in a 100 concurrent calls. 
I have already investigated into SynAttackProtect parameter and Backlog Queue and these were related to connection resets, so unrelated to my problem.
So in what cases will a Windows server suddenly issue a FIN, immediately after a successful TCP handshake?

Comment: what exactly "immediately" stands for?

Comment: @JanDvorak : After accepting the initial TCP Handshake with its SYN+ACK, the server sends a FIN+ACK packet to the client, thus gracefully closing the connection. The only HTTP request from the client was returned with an RST.

Answer (score 1):

**Http.sys intermittently ends TCP/IP connections in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2618425

Http.sys has been superseded since that hotfix was released.  If you want a more current version:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2634328

Comment: Thanks for the info. But in the above two cases you have mentioned, the connection is first closed by client. In my case, the server closes the connection with a FIN/ACK even before getting the first request from the client.